# specify columns to only allow number vals when edited (kendo grid)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Update:** I think I poorly worded this question; the issue is not the data coming from the rest call, the issue is: I would like to simply restrict some columns in my data grid from accepting 'alpha' characters, i.e. only except number input when a user is attempting to ***edit*** the field inline.. for instance, alpha characters could simply not writing, would work. Surely there is a easy method with kendo to do such a simple thing.

---

I have setup an editable kendo grid with the logic below coming from the rest call below; it populates fine but now I am trying to simply restrict some of my columns to only accept their data types, i.e. starting out I'm trying to set latitude and longitude to only accept number values; after trying the below, adding fields under id - instead of any actual validation on the latitude field, it adds a second latitude column to the grid?

```
        let dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
            url: "/popGrid?id=" + which,
            dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: { 
            data: "data",
            model: {
                id: id,
                fields: { // attempt doesnt effect current latitude col, adds another
                    latitude: { editable: true, type: "number",validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                    }
                }
            },
        });
```

Best way to go about this? I really don't want to hardcode each column out twice in order for a validation to take effect, I found one example doing so.. currently it's populating fine with my rest call and id model scheme dynamically, I just want to specify a few columns to only allow NUMBER input

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into kendo grid and this in fact might be a bug on their side. However there are work arounds for this to work.

You could either regex the numbers on the rest side, or you could simply parse the results on the schema side and only allow to pass numbers.

```
  schema: {
    parse: function(response) {
      var products = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var product = {
          response[i].replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); //replace all non-numeric characters with regular expression:
        };
        products.push(product);
      }
      return products;
    }
  }
```

As I don't see what kind of information and in what ambiance this is involved, stays difficult to help you further

Also possible to doit after de DOM with simple JS
With this second solution the user can't even type any kind of text other than numbers.

```
      $("#allow-numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
          var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
               
          if (!(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
            $(".error").css("display", "inline");
            return false;
          }else{
            $(".error").css("display", "none");
          }
      });
```

Make sure you replace the id with the same id in the schema.
Also you can had a flag to the schema for all the fields where you wanna implement this, living the other fields out of this rule

check snippet bellow

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#allow-numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
          var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
               
          if (!(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)) {
            $(".error").css("display", "inline");
            return false;
          }else{
            $(".error").css("display", "none");
          }
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JQuery - Allow only numeric values in Textbox - nicesnippets.com</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h1>JQuery - Allow only numeric values in Textbox</h1>
         
      <label>Enter Value:</label>
      <input type="text" name="myValue" class="allow-numeric" id='allow-numeric' >
      <span class="error" style="color: red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can document a bug, please file it at https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues

Comment: @KontYentE Thanks for responding; but the data coming from the rest is not the issue; I think you may have misunderstood the question. I just want to restrict a few columns from accepting chars when they are being 'edited' i.e. only accept numbers.

Comment: so on my opinion, the parse is the best solution. Whenever you try to edit something, it will first be parsed and then will be confirmed

Comment: Thanks.. in your example; what is your reference of 'products'?

Comment: You can replace the word products by results and product by result, if that helps you to better understand. In other words, the products is the response from REST. Whenever you type something on a field, it will send it to the dataSource and returns it. In this return, you'll be able to parse the result. That doesn't mean that you can't enter letters, but they will never be shown. There is another workaround which might be simple but not so efficient. You are setting an ID on the schema, so you can easily regest with jquery pointing to this id :) I'll update the solution with an example.

Comment: yes, but how to isolate it to effect one specific column only